# c library function to get number of active threads

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, posix, pthreads

I'm developing a multi threaded Unix application in C. Is there a simple way to get the count of the number of simultaneously active threads? I don't want to have to write the code to keep track of the number of active thread if it already can be done for me by the library! :-)

I'm using POSIX pthreads, and I'm trying to write as portable as possible code for Unix and Unix-like systems.

Comment: Depends on your threading library.  What threading library are you using, and on what platform?  Clarify the question, please.

Comment: clarification has been added!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not in pthreads *per se*.  POSIX Threads tries to specify only primitives or basic utility constructs, and [considers even `pthread_join` a convenience function, not a primitive](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_join.html#tag_03_533_08).

Certain libraries may offer non-portable solutions (look for `_np` in the name on HP-UX, for instance), but for pthreads *per se*, you're on your own.

Comment: @anonymous_downvoters, please detail your reasons for the downvotes!

Comment: Yeah, that was weird. I upvoted this one when I saw the downvotes. Please, give details on why.

Answer (score 1):

You could I guess keep a count of it in the constructor/destructor but make sure you handle it concurrently as to avoid race conditions.