# Where does the forked process start from if a call of fork in a thread occurs?

Tags: c, pthreads, fork

I'm going to write a program in which the main thread creates new thread and then the new thread creates a child process. Since I have a hard time keeping track of the new thread and forked process, I'd like to gain a wise answer from someone.

My question is

1. Does a created process in a thread start to execute codes after `pthread_create`?

2. If 1 is not, where does the forked process start from  if a call of fork in a thread  occurs?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Fork only clones the calling thread, if that is what you're asking about.

Comment: Then, does a forked process in a thread die if the thread routine in the forked process is complete?

Comment: I suppose you are asking about the case of calling fork but not exec, and the thread routine in the new process exits? I assume it would exit in that case, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Returning from the thread start function is equivalent to `pthread_exit`, and since `pthread_exit` is not async-signal-safe, calling it after `fork` in a multi-threaded program invokes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Yes, Assume that case of calling fork but not exec, and the thread start function in the process exit. Someone helps me...

Comment: I think in case that a process with two threads creates a child process, the child would inherit two threads from the parent. Is it correct? If it is correct, what does main thread in the child do? Main thread die? Main thread start to execute some codes after `pthread_create`?

Answer (score 0):

Some of this is a bit OS-dependent, as different systems have different POSIX thread implementations and this can expose internals.

POSIX offers `pthread_atfork` as a somewhat blunt instrument for dealing with some of the issues, but it still looks pretty messy to me.

If your system uses a one-to-one map between "user land thread" and "kernel thread" using `clone` or `rfork` to achieve proper user-space sharing of data between threads, then `fork` will merely duplicate the (single) thread that calls it.  However, if your system has a many-to-many style mapping (so that one user process is handling multiple threads, at least before they enter into blocking syscalls), `fork` may internally duplicate multiple threads.  POSIX says it should *look* like it only duplicated one thread, so that's not supposed to be visible, but I'm not sure how well all systems implement this.

There's some general advice at http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them (Linux-centric, obviously, but still useful).

Is there some particular reason you want to `fork` inside a thread but not `exec`?  In general, if you just want to run more code in parallel, you just spin off yet another thread (i.e., once you choose to run any threads, you do everything in threads, except if you have to `fork` for `exec`; if the `exec` fails, just `_exit`).

Comment: It's just a homework. I don't want to call `fork` inside a thread, too. Is there any way to check how many thread a process has?

Comment: No, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713129/c-library-function-to-get-number-of-active-threads

Comment: I have used `prtstat -r [pid]` command to check how many threads the process specified by `pid` has.

Comment: `prstat` appears to be a Solaris-specific command; it does not exist on MacOS and FreeBSD.  `prtstat` seems similarly to be Linux-specific.  So, there are OS-specific ways, but no generic pthread library.